# Tag Synonyms page - no info when hovering over Creator

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tooltips

On Tag Synonyms page, when I hover my mouse over the username in the Creator column, there's nothing displayed. Could it show reputation as in comments for example?

[image]